# Is there a way to do this without eval?

Tags: ruby

I don't see eval used by others much in ruby, so I'm assuming this can be done without it.  But I don't see how.

```
(1..9).each { |n|
    eval "user_#{n} = prefix << '_' << user_#{n} if user_#{n}"
}
```

Comment: Can you give explain a little what you are trying to accomplish? It seems like a bad idea to create 9 variables in this way. Perhaps an array or hash could serve the same purpose?

Comment: I'm not creating the variables, it's basically a formatting function where I am prefixing their user_id with a variable.  I do this as a way of ensuring they are unique when performing batch inserts.

Comment: Can you post the whole code file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite your code using a hash instead of local variables and you can ditch eval:

```
(1..9).each { |n|
  user[n] = prefix << '_' << user[n] if user[n]
}
```

BTW, I think you didn't want to use `<<` above as it will modify your `prefix` as well.

Comment: I agree with using a proper data structure, but if you're doing sequential numbers like this, I would strongly suggest an array rather than a hash.

Comment: It seems that some of the elements are not being set at all, that's why I suggested hash (as sparse array).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement this as an array, you can try

```
users.map! do |user|
  user ? "#{prefix}_#{user}" : nil
end
```

assuming that `users` is already defined.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a method dynamically using ruby's define_method.

You can replace `eval`-based statements with a `define_method` enclosed in a `class_eval`.

But, it depends on the situation. It might be overkill to replace `eval` with a dynamic method.

You need to provide more context for your question to get a better answer.